# Python Pandas, transposing DataFrameGroupBy object (Generating transpose of pandas grouped data)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

How can I generate a transpose of pandas grouped data. That is DataFrameGroupBy object
(DataFrame.T is not working for grouped data. Which is a DataFrameGroupBy object)

````
#Grouping data
def group_by(file_=None,column_=None):
    """Return data of the file grouped by column specified as the parameter"""
    data=load_data(file_)
    return data.groupby(column_)
#Transpose table to plot
def data_transpose(data_,grouped_=False,column_=None):
    """Create a transpose of the dataframe. If transposing grouped  data, set grouped_ to True and must specify column. Enter file, followed by boolean value then column name to group by to transpose grouped data"""
    #Each column corresponds to each county
    if grouped_:
        #must specify column
        grp_data=group_by(data_,column_)
        return grp_data.T
    data=load_data(data_)
    return data.T```
````

Comment: Please provide an example of input/. It is likely that what you want to do is not a transpose

Comment: Okay I don't have ready input to illustrate, but I want to group data by a particular column, then generate the transpose, to transform the row values of that column to be the column values of the dataset

Comment: Can't you craft a dummy example and the matching expected output?